# C# Hit Counter for My Website

Tags: c#

I have created the following code

```
var filename = "wwwroot/Counter/Counter.txt";
var counterStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
var reader = new StreamReader(counterStream);
var visits = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadLine());
visits = visits + 1;
var writer = new StreamWriter(counterStream);
writer.Write(visits);
counterStream.Dispose();
```

As you will realise, it is a hit counter for a website I am building. I am OK down to the line.

```
visits = visits + 1
```

Counter.txt is a file that just contains the one number and the above code has successfully read and updated it. However, the last three lines are not writing anything back to the file. I was half expecting it to write a new line in the file, although obviously I want it to replace the original. I am at a loss as to why it hasn't written anything. Could someone point me in the right direction, please.

Comment: Not an answer, but one important thing: didn't you think what would happen if 1000 users simultaneously open your website and your application tries to open 1000 file streams for the same file? :)

Comment: use `File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.Append)`

Comment: So much hassle for one number. Just use `File.ReadAllText` to read the number and `File.WriteAllText` to write it. like @YeldarKurmangaliyev mentioned - it's not threadsafe

Comment: I was hoping that FileShare.None would queue the open requests. I can't imagine there will be more than a handful trying to log on simultaneously. It is a website for a Bowling Club with a couple of hundred members, a lot of whom won't use a computer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Tip, you can use

```
using(FileStream counterStream=new FileStream())
{
}
```

Really handy as it will automatically dispose and clean up.

Here is an example that works, though it writes binary

```
using (FileStream counterStream = new FileStream("counter.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    uint counterVal = 0;
    byte[] buffer= new byte[4];
    if(counterStream.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length)>0)
    {
        counterVal = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0);
    }
            // Increment counter
    counterVal++;
    buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(counterVal);

            // Reset position (prevent writing a new line)
    counterStream.Position = 0;
    counterStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

But like Yeldar says, this will not work well with webservers due to collisions.
Also I think that your FileShare.None will prevent other users from opening the file, thus missing hits.

You could put it into a database instead, this will make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem with the following code

```
const string filename = "wwwroot/Counter/RLSBC.txt";
using (var counterStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
{
     int visits;
     using (var reader = new StreamReader(counterStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true, 4096, true))
     {
          string line = reader.ReadLine();
          int.TryParse(line, out visits);
     }
     visits = visits + 1;
     counterStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     using (var writer = new StreamWriter(counterStream))
     {
          writer.Write(visits);
     }
}
```